# Can I use the MySQL standard edition with XAMPP or I have to use the one which comes with it?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have the standard edition of MySQL which I use with Java and other things, and now I downloaded XAMPP to improve my experience with PHP programming, and of course I got a error when trying to use the MySQL which comes with XAMPP because it's listening to the same port as my standard version of MySQL, the only way to fix this is by changing one of the ports or is there a way to uninstall XAMPP's MySQL and use the standard edition with it instead ?

Comment: As i remember, you can choose **not** to install MySQL as a sevice when installing XAMPP. Then just don't start it.

Comment: But after choosing that option, how would I configure XAMPP to use the version which I have installed ?

Comment: I don't think there is anything to configure. You just connect to the existing MySQL server (localhost) within your PHP code.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it now and it really works that way, thank you sir !